# Arcpy RemoveLayer without ListLayers

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

I have an arcpy script which is bringing layers within a workspace into the table of contents, checking whether they contain features within the "current" extent of the mxd, and removing them if they are not. my script is as follows:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument ("CURRENT")
arcpy.env.workspace = 'Database Connections\database.sde'
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0] 
arcpy.env.extent = df.extent

dsList = arcpy.ListDatasets("", "Feature")  

for ds in dsList:
    fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*","",ds)
    for FC in fcList:
        try:
            addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(FC)
            addLayer.name = FC
            addLayer.visible = False
            arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df,addLayer,"AUTO_ARRANGE")

            for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,""):
                cnt = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(lyr).getoutput(0))
                if cnt<1:
                    arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df,lyr)
                del addLayer
        except:
            print "problem with: " + str(FC)
            pass
            del FC
        del fcList

print 'finished'
arcpy.RefrechTOC()
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.AddMessage("Appropriate Feature Layers Added")
mxd.save
del mxd
```

This script works, but the trouble is, the database that I am working with has become larger than it used to be, so much so that this tool takes too long to run now for it to be useful.

Question: is there a way to call arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer() outside of the 'for' loop of arcpy.mapping.ListLayers() in order to cut the size of the list the loop checks to 1?

Comment: Perhaps intersect 2 extents in memory and skip add layer if output is empty.

Comment: `arcpy.mapping.ListLayers` is **not** dependent on the number of tables in the database, but the number of Layers in the MapDocument. It's ListFeatureClasses which is the long pole in your tent.  Still, there are a number of ways to solve this that don't rely on double-nested loops.

Comment: It seems like you could create a view of SDE_Layers that exposes minx,miny,maxx and maxy.  That way you could open a cursor and just make one query of the database to find all featureclassnames that intersect your extent.

Comment: Your description of your tool isn't correct, it's not removing those that don't intersect but those that have no features, either way I'd do that **outside the loop**... if you really want to skip those that don't intersect get your dataframe extent http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s300000003000000 and your arcpy.describe(ds).extent http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Dataset_properties/03q30000008p000000/ and check for overlap *before adding the layer* avoiding the horrible double nested loop idea altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I was not achieving the goal I had described in my question. Instead of automatically adding the layer and conditionally removing it, I did not add the layer until a condition (containing features in the current env.extent) was met.

```
cnt  = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(lyr).getoutput(0))
if cnt<1:
    addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(FC)
    addLayer.name = FC
    addLayer.visible = False
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df,addLayer,"AUTO_ARRANGE")
```

was a more appropriate solution. It seems so simple now.